# Anaconda Navigator - Multiple Errors Encountered

Tags: anaconda

I recently broke my installation of Anaconda Navigator by using:

```
conda update --all -y
```

Apparently this is not uncommon, and it was a good excuse to reinstall Anaconda and start a new environment from scratch.

However, my new installation gives the following error, when trying to install any libraries:

[image: Multiple Errors Encountered]

I have tried:

- Windows uninstall of Anaconda, followed by reboot, then reinstall
- uninstall/reboot/install as admin
- uninstall/reboot/manually delete various remaining folders in the User directory/reboot/reinstall
- etc etc

All these methods produce this error, when trying to install libraries.

- install libraries using Anaconda console works fine
- there aren't any problems in Windows' PATH
- conda is up to date

What's going on!?

Comment: I have now seen several posts around the web that recommend *against* using conda update --all

Comment: I see you installed as admin, but are you selecting 'Run As Administrator' every time you launch Navigator? This appears to be necessary.

Comment: @obrl_soil: You are right. If Anaconda is installed as an admin, then every time you start Anaconda, it needs to be started as admin for package installation to work. Can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 25):

If you install Anaconda as admin, then you need to launch it as admin every time you run updates.

You can enable this behaviour by default by navigating to the Anaconda launch shortcut, right-click > Properties, go to Shortcut tab, click Advanced, and tick 'Always launch as administrator'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a new environment? I had the same message in another situation and that's what worked for me.

[image: Anaconda screen view]

Comment: Best solution if you cannot run as admin

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to download package and install it by yourself . 
here is a python package url https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Comment: Manual individual package updates negates the power of having an --all switch...